# DLL Reference issue with C++ (CLR support)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, unmanaged, lync-client-sdk

I am using one of the DLL file which is provided by Lync Client 2013 SDK (Microsoft.Lync.Model.dll -- version 15.0.4454.1509) in C++ code (with /CLR support). But during building the project it is not giving me any errors relevant to the code of Lync SDK class. But at run-time it is throwing me an error message:

(An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in scanuser.exe Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Lync.Model, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.)

```
//DLL I want to use
#using <Microsoft.Lync.Model.dll>

//namespace provided that DLL
using namespace Microsoft::Lync::Model;

//Function which is using that DLL
void getusername()
{
LyncClient ^lyncClient;
String     ^text=lyncClient->Self->Contact->GetContactInformation(ContactInformationType::DisplayName)->ToString();
Console::WriteLine(text);

}
```

I also added "**Additional #using Directories**" in which that DLL file is present that is:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\LyncSDK\Assemblies\Desktop"

*This DLL is working fine in sample applications which is written in C#. So I guess there is no problem with the sub-version of DLL*

**Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate,Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit,Lync Client SDK 2013**

So any ideas what's going on?

Comment: This is a problem when you use `#using`, that won't copy the DLL to your build directory.  Add a reference instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Problem solved just by adding reference of that DLL. Will you please elaborate on this issue as I am not used to with C++ having CLR support.